# How to set the color of H1 using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to know that how can i set the color of the text enclosed in H1 tag using javascript. For this i cant use css.

The script i tried was this-

```
document.h1.style.color="#fff"
```

But this doesnt work. Pls help.

EDIT-

I really couldnt find anything suitabble to this. Actually i do not know much about javascript and have encounter a problem where i have to use javascript to set the color of H1.

Now how can i do the same thing but with the p tag.

Comment: i used but could find a solution to my problem

Comment: U want to set color style to all <h1> elements or specific elements ?

Comment: @ameyarote, not advised to advise google searching! If you can provide an answer, that would help SO!

Comment: @InfantProgrammer'Aravind' - First of all anyone  must try to find answers by himself, if he/she fails he/she can ask ! Stopping to try anything first by yourself is you are under-estimating yourself. Beware of that.!

Comment: `Stopping to try anything first by yourself` what google returns then?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links

Comment: "what did you try on your end is **not** "google it first!!"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var h1Elements = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");

for(var i = 0; i < h1Elements.length; i++) {
   h1Elements[i].style.color = "#fff";
}
```

Comment: This is too complex for me. I just know html and css and very little about javascript.

Comment: @sdnr1 This is not complex nor complicated. In fact this is a correct and clear answer. If you (obviously) didn't even know the very basics of JS, you should start with a tutorial on JavaScript first.

Comment: This will work for me as it sets the color of all h1 elements. you did 1 mistake, that you didnt include 3

Comment: What do you mean? 3 what?

Comment: sorryy about that 3. i actually meant # before fff color

Comment: I don't think that answer is quite correct. It re-styles all current *h1* elements, but not *h1*.  I do it like this:  `st = document.createElement('style');st.innerHTML = 'h1{color:#fff}';document.head.appendChild(st)`

Answer (score 4):

You need to get the element. Lookup something like this :

```
document.getElementsByTagName('H1')[0]
```

then you just fiddle about with the attributes and styles.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works. Could you tell me that why this script doesnt work when i do not put [0] in the code?

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('H1')` will return an `array` of matched elements, now to apply the `.style` method, you need the DOM node. This will select the first match and apply the style.

Comment: But when i remove the [0], then this doesnt work

Comment: @sdnr1 Assume you have 2 `<h1>` tags. document.getElementsByTagName('H1') will give this -> `['h1','h1']`. Now to apply the style to the specifc element, you need the **specific** element, thus, the [`index number`].

Comment: @sdnr1 If you want to select all `h1`'s , this answer is incorrect, refer to [asgoth](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1916258/asgoth)'s answer.

Comment: i know and i did that only

Answer (score 1):

You can do it very easily with jQuery:

```
$('h1').css({'color' : '#fff'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please copy this code into any editor..Enjoy.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<h1 id="h1">The content</h1> <h1>of the body</h1> element is displayed in your browser.
</br></br></br>
<div onclick="checkAll()"> Click me To See Change</div>
</body>
<script>
function checkAll() {
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");  // Access all <H1> present in your body.

for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {   //divs.length contain number of <h1> elements
  var div = divs[i];                     // Now access Each <H1> one-by-one
  div.style.color = 'green';             // Set Color Style of each <h1>
}
}
</script>
</html>
```