# Trying to change an element's color with JavaScript and I get Undefined error

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events

I'm sorry if this sounds stupid , but after 3 hours trying to find an answer to this I'm at a loss. I just started learning Javascript for a university project.

So I am trying to dynamically change the color of some elements in my page using Javascript, and while this works for sole elements such as footer, I get an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined" in elements such as p or h4. I followed what I read on this thread : [How to set the color of H1 using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053390/how-to-set-the-color-of-h1-using-javascript/14053437)
but I'm still getting the error. Here is my code:

```
    const lightButton = document.getElementById("lighting_button");
console.log(lightButton);
const paragraph = document.querySelectorAll("p");
//console.log(p);

//console.log(contentHeader);
const bodyOfFile = document.body;

lightButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if(lightButton.textContent === "Dark Mode"){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#1a1a1a";

    document.querySelector('#footer').style.color = "#e6e6e6";

    const contentHeader = document.querySelectorAll("h4");

    for(let j=0; contentHeader.length-1; j++){
      contentHeader[j].style.color = "#ffffff";
    }

    for(let i=0; paragraph.length-1; i++){
      paragraph[i].style.color = "#e6e6e6";
    }
  }

});
```

The most bizarre thing is that it does make my h4 white even though there's an error. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a quick glance at your code, if I'm not mistaken, your loop syntax is not correct try replacing in both loops
`for(let j=0; j<contentHeader.length;j++`
The middle statement in your for loop is incorrect it should be a condition that returns true, in your case it's only trying for i=contentHeader.length-1

Comment: Oh my god you are so right! didnt think to check it 'cause it changed the color of all the elements before throwing the error, so I was so confused! Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Please mark my answer as correct 

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo in your for loop:

```js
const lightButton = document.getElementById("lighting_button");
//console.log(lightButton);
const paragraph = document.querySelectorAll("p");
//console.log(p);
//console.log(contentHeader);
const bodyOfFile = document.body;
lightButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if(lightButton.textContent === "Dark Mode"){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#1a1a1a";
   
        document.querySelector('#footer').style.color = "#e6e6e6";
    
        const contentHeader = document.querySelectorAll("h4");
    
        for(let j=0; j < contentHeader.length-1; j++){
          contentHeader[j].style.color = "#ffffff";
        }
    
        for(let i=0; i < paragraph.length-1; i++){
          paragraph[i].style.color = "#e6e6e6";
        }
      }
    
    });
```

```html
<button id="lighting_button">Dark Mode</button>
<h4>Title 1 </h4>
<h4>Title 2 </h4>
<h4>Title 3 </h4>
<h4>Title 4 </h4>
<h4>Title 5 </h4>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```